# izpack 4.3.4 programs and features

Tags: izpack

I am using IzPack 4.3.4 and I am trying to add my uninstaller to 
the Programs and Features section of the Windows control panel 
I am using Windows 10 (Build 10240).
But it does not seem to work, I modified the existing simple sample and added the following code to install.xml:

```
<natives>
   <native type="3rdparty" name="COIOSHelper.dll" stage="both">
   </native>
   <native type="3rdparty" name="COIOSHelper_x64.dll" stage="both">
   </native>
</natives>

<listeners>
    <listener classname="RegistryInstallerListener" stage="install"/>
    <listener classname="RegistryUninstallerListener" stage="uninstall"/>
</listeners>
```

Various sources, including the IzPack docs, state that this should make it work. But nothing appears in the Programs and Features list.

So what do I need to do in order to make this work?

Answer (score -1):

You also need ShellLink.dll for this to work:

```
  <natives>
    <native type="izpack" name="ShellLink.dll" />
    <native type="izpack" name="ShellLink_x64.dll" />
    <native type="3rdparty" name="COIOSHelper.dll" stage="both">
      <os family="windows" />
    </native>
    <native type="3rdparty" name="COIOSHelper_x64.dll" stage="both">
      <os family="windows" />
    </native>
  </natives>
```

Comment: Tried it, but it does not work. At least not for me.